# Search a string with Javascript

Tags: node.js, string, unit-testing

Hi everyone,

I am trying to test C programs that use an user input... Like a learning app. So the avaliator(teacher) can write tests and I compile the code with a help of a docker and get back the result of the program that I send. After that I verify if one of the case tests fails..

for that I have two strings, like this:

result = "input_compiled1540323505983: /home/compiler/input/input.c:9: main: Assertion `B==2' failed. timeout: the monitored command dumped core Aborted "

and an array with case tests that is like: 

    caseTests = [" assert(A==3); // A must have the value of 3;", " assert(B==2); // B must have the value of 2; ", " assert(strcmp(Fulano, "Fulano")==0); //Fulano must be equal to Fulano]

I need to send back from my server something like this:

{ console: [true, true, true ] }

Where each true is the corresponding test for every test in the array of tests

So, I need to test if one string contains the part of another string... and for now I did like this:

```
criandoConsole = function(arrayErros, arrayResult){
    var consol = arrayErros.map( function( elem ) {
        var local = elem.match(/\((.*)\)/);

        if(arrayResult.indexOf(local) > -1 ) { 
            return false;
        }
        else return true;
    }); 
    return consol;
}
```

I am wondering if there are any more efective way of doing that. I am using a **nodejs** as server. Does anyone know a better way?!

ps: Just do like `result.contains(caseTests[0])` did not work..

Answer (score 0):

I know this is changing the problem, but can you simplify the error array to only include the search terms? For example,

```
result = "input_compiled1540323505983: /home/compiler/input/input.c:9: main: Assertion `B==2' failed. timeout: the monitored command dumped core Aborted ";

//simplify the search patterns
caseTests = [
"A==3",
"B==2",
"strcmp(Fulano, \"Fulano\")==0"
]

criandoConsole = function(arrayErros, arrayResult){
    var consol = arrayErros.map( function( elem ) {
    if (arrayResult.indexOf(elem) != -1)
      return false; //assert failed?
    else
      return true; //success?
    });
    return consol;
}

console.log(criandoConsole(caseTests,result));
```

Comment: I did not try this, but I think It's possible.. If I change in the application before call my server. It would eliminate one regex for the "search"... and I am getting trouble with the time response on the server. Thanks for your comment I will try this..